# Spring data mongodb Aggregation group and count

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I want to make group and count a collection data by its nested field **type.name**. However, spring data mongo db's Aggregation count static method return 1 as count for each type, eventhough there are more then 1 data for each type. Is there any mistake my pipeline functions ? If so could you correct me please ? Thanks in advance

My collection data structure is:
[image]

java code to fetch data:

```
private List<OrganizationSummary> getOrganizationSummary(){
    Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
            match(Criteria.where("status").is(Boolean.TRUE).and("deleted").is(Boolean.FALSE)),
            group("type.name").count().as("count"),
            project("count").and("name").previousOperation()
    );

    AggregationResults<OrganizationSummary> groupResults
            = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, Organization.class, OrganizationSummary.class);
    List<OrganizationSummary> result = groupResults.getMappedResults();
    return result;
}
```

result from debugger. As you see all count fields are default 1, eventhough there are more then 1 data for each type.

[image]

Result from mongoshell:

[image]

Result dto to be projected:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class OrganizationSummary {
   private String name;
   private Long count;
}
```

Logs after **mongoTemplate.aggregate()** method is executed.

```
06-10-2022 15:04:18 [DEBUG] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate                        : Executing aggregation: [{ "$match" : { "status" : true, "deleted" : false}}, { "$group" : { "_id" : "$type.name", "count" : { "$sum" : { "$date" : "1970-01-01T00:00:00.001Z"}}}}, { "$project" : { "count" : { "$date" : "1970-01-01T00:00:00.001Z"}, "_id" : { "$date" : "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"}, "name" : "$_id"}}] in collection organization
    06-10-2022 15:04:18 [DEBUG] org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command                                        : Sending command '{"aggregate": "organization", "pipeline": [{"$match": {"status": true, "deleted": false}}, {"$group": {"_id": "$type.name", "count": {"$sum": {"$date": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.001Z"}}}}, {"$project": {"count": {"$date": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.001Z"}, "_id": {"$date": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"}, "name": "$_id"}}], "cursor": {}, "allowDiskUse": false, "$db": "organizationidentity", "lsid": {"id": {"$binary": {"base64": "GA/dUO4HRlWxF1m9NVs1iQ==", "subType": "04"}}}}' with request id 22 to database organizationidentity on connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:78}] to server localhost:27017
    06-10-2022 15:04:18 [DEBUG] org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command                                        : Execution of command with request id 22 completed successfully in 13.70 ms on connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:78}] to server localhost:27017
    06-10-2022 15:04:18 [DEBUG] org.mongodb.driver.operation
```

Comment: Please include code instead of images.

Comment: Code snipets added as text. Thanks.

Comment: Your query seems fine. Are you sure there is data where counts are greater than 1